# JavaScript: After calling a function from form onsubmit event, server side code is not executed

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm calling a function from a form onsubmit event:

```
   <form runat="server" onsubmit="ShowLoading();">
   <div id="prnt" runat="server" ></div>
    </form>

     <script type="text/javascript">
   function ShowLoading(e) {
       var div = document.createElement('div');
       div.setAttribute("id", "loadingMsg");
       var img = document.createElement('img');
       img.src = 'images/ld_gif2.gif';
       div.style.cssText = 'position: fixed; top: 30%; left: 40%; z-index: 5000; width: 222px; text-align: center; ';
       div.appendChild(img);
       var parnt = document.getElementById('prnt');
       parnt.appendChild(div);
   }

   </script>
```

The button that triggers submission:

```
   <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server"  CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnSave_Click"/>
```

The function ShowLoading() is executed successfully as supposed, but the server side function btnSave_Click is not called.

Could you please help me.

Comment: Are you sure it's the form's `onsubmit` callback that's the problem? Nothing immediately jumps out above. You're not preventing the default action, so the form should submit normally. Try temporarily removing the `onsubmit` and see if the form submits, I suspect the problem is not in the code shown.

Comment: I tried to remove the onsubmit and my server side code worked normally.

Comment: Huh. Do you have any errors in the web console on your browser? (**Always** look there first. :-) )

Comment: It's **not** the problem, but I will just note that your `ShowLoading` function expects a parameter (`e`), but you're not calling it with any argument for that parameter. (That's okay in JavaScript, though; `e` will get the value `undefined`. I say it's not the problem since you don't use `e` anywhere in the function, so the fact it comes through as `undefined` doesn't matter.)

Comment: I don't have any errors ( i've inspected the page).